# On this, why does it only work after aliasing?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, syntax-error, alias

Below query resulted in "Unrecognized name: bigquery at [8:8]" error :

```
WITH longest_used_bike AS(
  SELECT bike_id,SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration
  FROM bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips
  GROUP BY bike_id
  ORDER BY trip_duration DESC
  LIMIT 1
)

SELECT 
  bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips.start_station_id, 
  COUNT(*) AS trip_ct
FROM bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips
JOIN longest_used_bike
  ON longest_used_bike.bike_id = bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips.bike_id
GROUP BY start_station_id
ORDER BY trip_ct DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But below query works after aliasing:

```
WITH longest_used_bike AS (
  SELECT bike_id,SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration
  FROM bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips
  GROUP BY bike_id
  ORDER BY trip_duration DESC
  LIMIT 1
)

SELECT
  trips.start_station_id,
  COUNT(*) AS trip_ct
FROM bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips as trips
JOIN longest_used_bike as longest
  ON longest.bike_id = trips.bike_id
GROUP BY start_station_id
ORDER BY trip_ct DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Project, dataset, column and table names are "identifiers". Identifiers can only contain certain characters when they are not quoted, else you must quote them with `` ` ``.

> Unquoted identifiers
>
> - Must begin with a letter or an underscore (_) character.
> - Subsequent characters can be letters, numbers, or underscores (_).
>
> Quoted identifiers
>
> - Must be enclosed by backtick (`) characters.
> - Can contain any characters, including spaces and symbols.
> - Cannot be empty.
> - Have the same escape sequences as string literals.

So `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips` must be quoted because of the dashes. But only quote the identifiers, not the dots.  `` `bigquery-public-data`.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips ``

*However*, BigQuery makes an exception for table names with dashes, but *only in the from clause*. Presumably because BigQuery likes to name projects with dashes.

> A table name that is an unquoted identifier can additionally include single dashes if the table name is referenced in a FROM or TABLE clause. Only the first identifier in the table path (the project ID or the table name) can have dashes. Dashes are not supported in datasets.

So `from bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips` is fine, but `select bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips.start_station_id` is not. It would be `` select `bigquery-public-data`.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips.start_station_id ``

By using an alias for the table name you are side-stepping the issue, and also making the query easier to read.

See [BigQuery lexical structure and syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical) for more detail.

Comment: I see, thank you for the answer and the edit on the post. The query runs without an error now, but does not give me any results. It returns "There is no data to display" while the 'alias version' of the query does return the number of trips of that one bike.

Comment: @Kiv I can't say without seeing the new query. I've seen several questions about this longest bike trip, is this some sort of course?

Comment: Yes, it's part of the Google Data Analytics Certificate Program. The new query I was referring to is the second one on my original post.

Comment: @Kiv "*The query runs without an error now, but does not give me any results.*" What query is this referring to?

Comment: The original non-aliased query but quoted bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips in the SELECT clause

Comment: @Kiv Please paste the whole query somewhere, [here for example](https://gist.github.com/), and provide the link. You generally need to quote the individual parts, not the dots. ```select `bigquery-public-data`.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips.start_station_id```. Though if you did quote the whole thing that should result in an error because the literal column `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips.start_station_id` does not exist.